# Catkin and overlays

Tags: ros, catkin, overlay

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Just to recap the [workspace_overlaying](http://ros.org/wiki/catkin/Tutorials/workspace_overlaying) tutorial, I have two catkin based workspaces `catkin_A` and `catkin_B`. I want to configure them so that the `catkin_A` overlays ROS standard packages and `catkin_B` overlays `catkin_A`. Assuming that both have been properly initialised and filled with packages as follows

```
$ source /opt/ros/hydro/setup.bash
$ mkdir -p ~/catkin_X/src
$ cd ~/catkin_X/src; catkin_init_workspace
```

So to set up the overlay structure i do

```
$ source /opt/ros/hydro/setup.bash
$ cd ~/catkin_A
$ catkin_make
```

and

```
$ source ~/catkin_A/devel/setup.bash
$ cd ~/catkin_B
$ catkin_make
```

In order to use the `catkin_B` workspace I have to source `$ source ~/catkin_B/devel/setup.bash`. The `$ source ~/catkin_A/devel/setup.bash` is the crucial part as the tutorial says the question is do I have to do it every time I call `catkin_make` in the `catkin_B` to clear the `catkin_B` from environment?

How about `catkin_make` in `catkin_A` if I have previously used `catkin_B` do I have to `source /opt/ros/hydro/setup.bash'?

I'm asking this question as the overlay setup gets broken from time to time, `rosrun` starts looking in `/opt/ros/hydro` for nodes that should be overlaid in `catkin_A`.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/74293/catkin-and-overlays/) by [liborw](https://answers.ros.org/users/2302/liborw/) on ROS Answers with karma: 801 on 2013-08-22

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) on 2013-08-22**:
Btw. the invocation of catkin_init_workspace is not necessary. That will be implicitly done by catkin_make.

**Comment by [liborw](https://answers.ros.org/users/2302/liborw/) on 2013-08-22**:
Thanks I didn't know that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

No. It sets bash environment variables.

You need to run it once for each time you open a new shell (or terminal). If you almost always use `catkin_B`, just source it in your `~/.bashrc`, which automatically runs each time you open a new shell.

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2013-08-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [liborw](https://answers.ros.org/users/2302/liborw/) on 2013-08-22**:
I probably wasn't clear so I updated the question.